# Do you walk up or climb stairs

Tags: word-choice

Is it more correct to say "I climbed up the stairs" or "I walked up the stairs"?

*Climb* is defined as

> go or come up a (slope or staircase); ascend.

*Walk* is defined as

> an act of travelling or an outing on foot.

Both are theoretically correct, but is one more correct than the other?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=climbed+the+stairs%2C+walked+up+the+stairs%2C+climbed+up+the+stairs&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclimbed%20the%20stairs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwalked%20up%20the%20stairs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclimbed%20up%20the%20stairs%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Neither is more correct. They mean different things.

Comment: Why does one have to be "more correct" than the other?

Comment: @HotLicks One does not _have_ to be more correct than the other. I am asking if one of them _is_ more correct than the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Merriam-Webster:

> **climb**: to move or go up (something) using your feet and often your hands

From Dictionary.com:

> **climb**: to ascend, go up, or get to the top of, especially by the use of the hands and feet or feet alone or by continuous or strenuous
>   effort: to climb a rope; to climb the stairs; to climb a mountain

Because **climb** when used without an adverb or prepositional phrase (e.g., *over*, *over the rocks*, *down*, *down the stairs*) implies "up", one should leave out "up" in this case.

So, either of the following would be equally correct:

> I climbed the stairs. (Not "I climbed up the stairs.")
>
> OR
>
> I walked up the stairs.

Comment: Climb doesn't imply up. You can just as easily climb down something.

Comment: @MrLister Perfectly true, but we do *climb stairs, climb mountains, and climb buildings*. However we *climb down a mineshaft*, and *we climb down from on high*. In other words with the word *climb* the presumption is that it means *up*, unless *down* is specified.

Comment: @WS2 Illuminating point re "down" versus "up".

Comment: @WS2 I revised my answer to incorporate your insight.

Comment: @RichardKayser There wouldn't be anything much wrong with saying *I climbed up the stairs*, or *I climbed up the mountain* for that matter. But it is not the usual idiomatic form, that is all. However *climb up* does provide a nuanced variant - perhaps implying that it was all done rather more easily and quickly than would be realistic. (At least that would be my view of *climb up*. Others may feel differently.).

Comment: As regards the original question, if I were talking about our own stairs at home, which I use every day, I think I would say *I walked up the stairs*, or *I went upstairs*. However if I visited a tall building and the lifts (elevators) were not working, I might say *I had to climb the stairs to the eighteenth floor*. If I had to go into my loft (attic) at home I would probably say *I climbed up the loft ladder*. Our speech is highly nuanced but it is not always easy to spot the rules which we all employ, without thinking, every day.

Answer (score 3):

As a UK English speaker, I do not think there is a BIG difference between "I climbed up the stairs" or "I walked up the stairs". It’s a matter of emphasis. You can also say “I went up the stairs”.

If you just mean you are going to the upper floor of a house, it is most common just to say "I went upstairs". In this case, upstairs is a place: “the bedroom is upstairs”. So "I went upstairs" just means I went to that place. The route taken and the method are unspecified. You could say "the bird flew upstairs", but it could clearly not fly up THE stairs.

“I went up the stairs” emphasises the stairs as the route taken: "I went up the stairs because the lift is broken"; "I cannot fly, so I went up the stairs".

"I walked up the stairs" emphasises walking as the method used to get upstairs "the old woman walked up the stairs instead of using her stair-lift". “She has trouble walking up stairs due to arthritis”. It might also emphasis both the method and the route “The lift is broken and I am exhausted because I had to walk up the stairs”.

"He climbed the stairs" is something you might find in older books simply meaning he went upstairs, but nowadays it implies some abnormal effort "the baby climbed the stairs today without any help”; “though shot in the leg he nevertheless managed to climb the stairs”.

Comment: It is probably an exaggeration to say that *climb* 'implies some abnormal effort', but the answer is on the right track in so far as it brings out that *climb* emphasises the upward direction in the way in way in which *walk up* does not. People are thus more likely to use *climb up* for steep staircases.