# Is 'I was climbing down the road' correct?

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis

My friend Thomas asked me to come in his home with my brother Solomon. So me and my brother were on the way to his house. Thomas called me (on the phone) while I was on my way over and asked me "where did you reach?"

Then I replied, "I'm climbing down the road". As soon as I said that sentence, my brother started laughing and pointed me out that it is not a correct sentence.

Actually at that moment I was very tired and that road was also very steep (hard slope). And I was having difficulty walking down that road. So I was trying to express my tiredness to my friend. My question is whether it is correct to use 'climbing down' instead of 'walking down' in a sentence?

Comment: google 'climb(ing) down'. Lots of info!

Comment: We walk down an incline, but climb down stairs.

Comment: It's correcter than "where did you reach".

Comment: @NigelJ I normally walk down stairs. Can't speak for anyone else, of course.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Interesting. I did the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=climb+down+stairs%2Cwalk+down+stairs&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclimb%20down%20stairs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwalk%20down%20stairs%3B%2Cc0) for both and was surprised. And even more surprised that BrE returns nothing for 'climb'.

Comment: Having sorted out the climbing thing, we might now have a look at 'me and my brother was on the way to his house'.

Comment: There is a lot of incorrect terminology in the question but i focused on the direct question in the last sentence. " My friend Thomas asked me to come in his home with my brother Solomon " to me implies that they were already there, and that " asked me to come to his house with my brother would be more appropriate". Come in his home makes it sound like they were standing outside of it presently

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically speaking, *climbing down something* is correct. In this case, however, you say you were *"climbing down the road"*, which is probably not correct (assuming the road is in such a way that you can normally walk it).

*To climb down something* is normally used for literally **climbing** down something, for example a ladder or a climbing wall. Some more examples on correct usage can be found in [this question on this website](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/349436/is-it-correct-to-use-climb-down-the-stairs-in-a-sentence).

Comment: #JJJ, I was very tired at that moment and I was trying to express my tiredness, as the road was too steep (if I walk down to that road it's difficult to walk up because of steepness.).

Comment: @Tozum, I understand, however, as the [OED defines it according to this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/349447/71848), _to climb_ is to "raise oneself by **grasping or clinging**, or by the aid of **hands and feet**". It goes on to say _to climb down_ is "to descend by the same means". I don't think your walking down that road is quite the same, i.e. it would not qualify as climbing. 

More accurately (perhaps already stretching the definition), you could say you [_walked uphill_](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/uphill):  "going up a slope".

Answer (score 0):

I would say one climbs down a ladder, but not a road. In order to express your exhaustion you could in turn use the word "trudge".

> trudge
>
> verb 1.walk slowly and with heavy steps, typically because of
>   exhaustion or harsh conditions.
>
> noun
>   1.a difficult or laborious walk.

*"I am trudging down the road"*

Alternatively you could also use "trek", but i feel like trudge conveys how tired you were better.

> > Trek
>
> Noun 1. a long arduous journey, especially one made on foot

*"I am trekking down the road"*